# Swift Cognito "Missing Authentication Token" from HTTP Body

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-cognito

I am using cognito development which works great in android but its not working in swift if someone can help.

Class files are autogenerated so I am not writing here, I am just writing the code to call the function,

```
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.APSoutheast2,credentialsProvider: nil)
let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "ClientID", clientSecret: "ClientSecret", poolId: "PoolID")
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: configuration, userPoolConfiguration: userPoolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")

let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .APSoutheast2, identityPoolId: "ap-southeast-2:xxx", identityProviderManager:pool)

AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let serviceClient = APICLient.default();

credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block:{(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
    serviceClient.eventGet().continueWith(block: {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        self.showResult(task: task as! AWSTask<AnyObject>)
        return nil
})
})
```

When I try to execute error comes from HTTP that is

```
HTTPBody={
    message = "Missing Authentication Token";
}}
```

Do anyone have suggestion on swift? Android have complete different code and its working good with same server. But for swift there is no way I can pass token.

Pramit

Comment: You did not set token?

Comment: `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration` doesn't seem to be present inside the ios sdk... which version are you using?

Comment: Does this sample help? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift/CognitoSyncDemo